# Valgrind stops after few hours

Tags: valgrind

I am trying to find a memory leak on a process that will need a few days to run, but after several attempts it seems that Valgrind stops after few hours.

Is it possible to run it for longer periods (days)?

Answer (score 0):

valgrind does not stop by itself.

Either the guest process has called exit or crashes or something in the OS is killing valgrind, such as OOM killer or cpu quota or ...